# Is it possible to join eloquent relationship query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a users, departments, and positions table.

I want to select one department with all the users in that department with their position name.

Currently, I have this.

```
$department = DepartmentView::with('users')
            ->findOrFail($departmentId);
```

It returns me a department with users, but I want to join the users with positions table so I can also get the position name. (user table only has position id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your relationships setup properly in your User model and the relationship is called `position`, it should be like this:

```
$department = DepartmentView::with('users.position')
            ->findOrFail($departmentId);
```

Look at [eager loading -> nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
$department = DepartmentView::with('users.position')->findOrFail($departmentId)
```

`position` is referred to the relationship set on the User model to get the user position.